# Dificuldade de esconder parte de um formulário com UserControl

Tags: c#, asp.net

Tenho um formulário chamado frmCadastroBens que declara um UserControl, que chamo de wucCadastroBens. Nesse formulário eu registro os UC assim:

```
<%@ Register src="WUC/wucCadastroBens.ascx" tagname="wucCadastroBens" tagprefix="uc1" %>
<%@ Register src="WUC/wucCadastroBens.ascx" tagname="wucCadastroBens" tagprefix="uc2" %>
<%@ Register src="WUC/wucCadastroBens.ascx" tagname="wucCadastroBens" tagprefix="uc3" %>
```

E depois assim:

```
<uc1:wucCadastroBens ID="wucCadastroBensNovoPV" runat="server" />
    <br />
    <uc2:wucCadastroBens ID="wucCadastroBensUsadosPV" runat="server" />
    <br />
    <asp:RadioButtonList RepeatDirection="Horizontal" ID="rdbGarantiaConfissao" runat="server" RepeatLayout="Flow" RepeatColumns="0" CellSpacing="-1">
        <asp:ListItem Text="Confissão de Dívida " Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="Garantia Adicional"  Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
    <uc3:wucCadastroBens ID="wucCadastroConfissaoDividaPV" runat="server" />
```

Acontece que eu preciso, no momento de clicar no botão CadastrarNovo, eu esconder os demais UC, deixa eu explicar. É apenas um UC, registrado da forma como falei acima. Quando eu estiver no uc1, eu devo mostrar o Painel de Cadastro e esconder os demais. O problema que é um painel apenas e esse método está dentro do wucCadastroBens.cs e não no frmCadastroBens.cs. Se estivesse dentro do frmCadastroBens.cs, eu faria assim: `wucCadastroBensUsadosPV.Visible = false;` isso daria certo, mas acontece que eu estou dentro do wuc e não consigo mais ter "3" "painéis", por exemplo, como eu tenho no frmCadastrBens. Então vem a pergunta: Como eu posso fazer, para que no momento de cadastrar um bem novo, eu esconder os demais painéis(um para cada wuc registrado no frmCadastroBens). No momento quando a página é carregada, fica aparecendo os três painéis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente fazer o seguinte:
Em frmCadastroBens.cs adicione um metodo publico que altere a visibilidade dos UserControl.

```
public void setUCVisible(wucCadastroBens userControl) { ... }
```

Então dentro do UserControl, faça o seguinte:

```
var parent = this.Parent.Page as frmCadastroBens;
parent.setUCVisible(this);
```

Comment: Está dando esse erro: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Esqueci de acessar a propriedade Page do Control Parent.

Comment: Qualquer erro aqui é terreno novo para mim. Vou testar e já posto.